# Qt data types error with big numbers

Tags: qt, numbers

i have a problem with huge numbers. i retrieve a number out of QSettings.

```
settings.beginGroup( "filesizes" );
this->fileSize = settings.value( 309355 ).toLongLong();
qDebug() << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::max();              
qDebug() << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "this->filesize: " << this->fileSize;
qDebug() << "loaded filesize" << this->fileSize;
```

The number stored in settings is 12062891612 (~11,x GB in bytes). The fourth line returns me "-822010276" and i don't understand why. this->fileSize is qint64. I reduced the number in settings and as long as it's smaller then 2147483647 (2^31-1) everything is alright, but above i get negative numbers. i don't understand that, because longlong and qint64 should be enough?!
does anyone have an idea, whats going wrong?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does using `QVariant::toULongLong()` instead gives the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your datatype to quint64 in order to get a bigger maximum size of 2^32-1.  It only gives you one extra bit, and it actually looks like you might out grow that at some point soon and will need to come up with a more creative solution, like storing your size in KB or MB in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be at some other place. The provided piece of code works ok, and neither `QSettings` nor `QVariant` does any truncations of long long values.